# filtering realm list doesn't update list view

Tags: xamarin.forms, realm

I am just picking up Realm and was trying out the [QuickJournal](https://github.com/realm/realm-dotnet/tree/master/examples/QuickJournal) example present on GitHub in Xamarin Forms

After the entries are load up in the list view from the constructor as below

```
 public JournalEntriesViewModel()
    {
        _realm = Realm.GetInstance();

        Entries = _realm.All<JournalEntry>();

       .. .
    }
```

I added a search bar and was trying to filter and update the Entries collection

```
public string Filter
{
  get
  {
    retur _filter;
  }
  set
  {
    _filter = value;
    Filter();
  }
}


private void Filter()
{
   Entries = _realm.All<JournalEntry>().Where(i => i.Title.StartsWith(_filter));
}
```

The Filter property is bound to the SearchBar Text in Xaml and the Entries list changes but the UI never updates. My impression was that since Realm uses Fody the notification is propagated to the UI to update.

I have also tried the below change using ToList to fire off the query & map it to realm core as mentioned in the documentation but to no avail. Converting Entries to RealmCollection doesn't work either

```
Entries = _realm.All<JournalEntry>().ToList().Where(i => i.Title.StartsWith(_filter));
```

Can someone kindly explain what I am missing here

Many Thanks

Comment: Try changing _filter with property name(Filter).

Answer (score 0):

I managed to workaround this by firing a PropertyChanged event for the Entries property to update the UI after assigning the value.